# Windows 8.1 64bit Pro key to activate 32bit Home?

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, 32-bit, license, license-key

I have a Lenovo Yoga Tablet 2-1051F here where the license key somehow got deleted. Restoring keys in the BIOS and doing a factory reset did not help. So now I am looking for a key in order to activate the device. The tablet has Windows 8.1 32bit Home installed.

*What keys are compatible with that version? Can I also use a key for Windows 8 64bit Pro?* (easier to obtain)

Comment: “What keys are compatible with that version?“ - Windows 8 or Windows 8.1;  if you use a Windows 8 Professional key it will be upgraded to Professional.  Windows 8 license keys are compatible with Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 installations.  Windows 8.1 license keys can only activate Windows 8.1

Comment: “Restoring keys in the BIOS and doing a factory reset did not help.” - It should have which an indicator you installed the incorrect edition of Windows 8.1

Comment: @Ramhound Well, I did the factory reset using the functionality provided when starting the machine with the volume up button pressed. That displays the *Novo Menu*, from where one can reset the system. So it is highly unlikely that the wrong edition of Windows 8.1 was installed.

Comment: So what is the actual problem?  You performed a Refresh, which kept your personal files but reinstalled Windows.  Is it the fact the installation is not activated?  That is a simple problem to solve.

Comment: @Ramhound Not a refresh, I did a complete reset to factory defaults. The Microsoft key server does not accept the key in the BIOS: *This key didn't work, please check it and try again, or try a different key.* This is the problem.

Comment: If you have problems with activating an OEM-provided Windows license, you need to contact the OEM’s support.

Comment: @DanielB I contacted Microsoft twice today. Customer service representatives logged onto the system, and the second one was able to resolve the issue. Apparently there was something broken. That's fixed now, and Windows 8.1 is activated with the original key.

Answer (score -1):

Usually a key is not specific to the system type unless your tablet is a 32-bit only infrastructure. If you have the software and the key for it win pro and pro key, it should be fine.